# i want to get my result with 2 decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, tofixed

Below is the code I currently using which I need to round the end result to 2 decimals.Can someone help me figure out what I did wrong.

```js
total = panjang*ht+hf;
document.getElementById("ototal").innerHTML =eval(total(toFixed(2)));
```

Comment: `total.toFixed(2)`?

Comment: Did you try reading any [doco for `.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to see how it is supposed to be used? Also, you don't need `eval()`.

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary

Comment: Why are you using eval??

Answer (score 2):

The variable `total` is a number, not a `function`.
You should use `toFixed` function like this

```
total.toFixed(2)
```

Comment: This is a very low quality question.  Please don't answer such low quality questions like this.  Leave a comment, but don't answer.